# What happens when writing to a device driver?

Tags: linux, devices, system-calls

What happens when writing to a device driver?

For example:

```
echo "some text" > /proc/device_driver
```

I'm guessing that echo has a write-call that somehow invokes the write-function in the driver. 
What are the "steps" from the echo-function to the drivers write function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the *The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide* (*[5.2. Read and Write a /proc File](http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x769.html)*), the kernel calls a function associated with the driver during the driver's initialization to read the data from *userspace* into the *kernel*.

The `echo` program does not know anything special about the kernel; the kernel does all of the work.

Further reading:

- [How to read/write from/to a linux /proc file from kernel space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400200/how-to-read-write-from-to-a-linux-proc-file-from-kernel-space)
- [How to write a kernel module for Linux](http://cs.smith.edu/~nhowe/262/oldlabs/module.html)